# fstab и монтирование ФС обычным пользователем

Tags: linux, fedora, fstab

Вопрос скорее имеет познавательный характер, чем практический, но всё-же.

Фрагмент fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/vmf              /vmf        ext2    noauto,nofail,user,noexec,rw 0 2
```

Насколько я понимаю, что такая ФС не будет промонтирована автоматически при загрузке. Её может монтировать обычный пользователь

```
]$ mount /dev/disk/by-label/vmf
```

Ну а при двойном клике на значёк ФС на рабочем столе все-равно запрашивается пароль администратора.

1. Можно ли сделать, чтобы пароль не запрашивался,
2. Или монтировалась автоматически при первом обращении к /vmf

Comment: 1 — да можно, по идее нужно подправить правила polkit'а для этого действия... но честно сказать, у меня правильно и чисто настроить это ни когда не получалось. 2 — можно воспользоваться `autofs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В полките есть такое правило:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab">
    <description>Mount/unmount filesystems defined in the fstab file with the x-udisks-auth option</description>
...
<defaults>
  <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Добавить `x-udisks-auth` в фстаб

Правила в `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy` на эту политику поставить

```
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Без `fstab`, просто по клику, можно разрешить в политике `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system`. Системные разделы сломать не должен, тк там куча процессов, которые не дадут отмонтировать рут налету.

Чтоб не затерлось при обновлении политику нужно скопировать куда-то в `/var/`

Answer (score 2):

Если её может монтировать обычный пользователь, то почему бы не создать простенький bash скрипт, на том же рабочем столе, раз есть такая необходимость. Пожалуй, это будет наиболее простым решением проблемы.

Comment: Можно и так... Но тут непонятный момент, зачем прописывать в fstab точку монтирования, если нет авто. Пользователь же потом может смонтировать её в любой другой раздел.

Comment: *зачем прописывать в fstab точку монтирования, если нет авто* - именно для того,  что бы можно было выдать потом команду *mount* без ключей и второго параметра.